# I am trying to fetch the availableFromDate field for the product Id =Product3 from the response Here the product id keep on changing while hitting API

Tags: testing, karate

I am trying to fetch the availableFromDate field for the product Id =Product3 from the response. how to resolve this scenario?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

And def date3 = response.body[0].productId[2].availableFromDate

- print date3

Comment: Here position of product ID keeps on changing whenever we are hitting API, The above payload is just a sample.